# how to custom this kind of recurrent NN in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

[image]

As you can see, I'm gonna construct this sort of recurrent NN. But I have no idea what kinda Keras function to finish the abstract requirements. The hidden state from the LSTM from the last timeslice is fed to the next timeslice.

In fact, I have tried many times with RNN(). And I have asked you all  for a corresponding question here: [to custom RNN with LSTMcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442362/to-custom-rnn-with-lstmcell)